# Rebase Git history after git subtree

Tags: git, github, git-subtree

I was using git subtree for the `gh-pages` deployment from [this guide](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490):

```
git subtree push --prefix build origin gh-pages
```

I have never use git subtree before, it actually does the job that my app is deployed to `gh-pages` successfully, but when I check the git history, it's totally a mess with a lot of strange "branches".

[image]

I want to mention that during the deployment, sometimes I have to pull the subtree with `git subtree pull --prefix build origin gh-pages` to resolve some conflicts that at the time I wasn't sure why.

Now I trying to clean up the history by reset it to the moment before the subtree, here is what I see:

[image]

I trying to remove all those strange-anonymous "branches" and get a clean, nice and meaningful history on master branch.

Any help or useful document where I can read to understand this is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This is `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all`:

[image: git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all]

This is `git branch -vv`

[image: git branch -vv]

Comment: Looks like the branch is fully merged in and shouldn't pose any major issues.  But...are you using `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all`?  If you're not, that *might* show you a bit more information.  Otherwise, what does `git branch -vv` tell you?

Comment: It was `git log --graph --oneline --decorate` (without `--all`). The `--all` option does have more information as it show all the branches which seem to me a huge mess, still can't find a way to clean this (Image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mzEjx.png). Git branch show all the branches I'm currently have: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z7Q7.png

Comment: Would you mind adding those pictures to your question?  From what I can see the only two branches which GitHub cares about are gh-pages and master.

Comment: @Makoto I added the pictures to the question. Yes there are only 2 branches but the merges are so complicated. Do you have any idea clean it up?